# Adding Explain Plans together from a split SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

We have a procedure that uses a huge SQL Query to retrieve information, then insert it into a another table `XX_REP_TABLE`. The SQL query is below:

```
SELECT
    xx_det.ledger_id,
    << ... more where clauses ... >>
    nvl(xx_line.tax_calculation_formula, 'STANDARD_TC')  tax_line_user_attribute14,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY xxx_rcpt_line.accounting_class_code, xxx_rcpt_dist.source_distribution_id_num_1, xxx_rcpt_dist.
        event_id) = 1 THEN
            NULL
        WHEN ( ( xxx_rcpt_line.overridden_code_combination_id IS NULL
                 AND xxx_rcpt_line.override_reason IS NOT NULL )
               OR ( EXISTS (
            SELECT
                'Reversal of original due to override exists'
            FROM
                xxx_ae_lines            xal2,
                xxx_distribution_links  xdl2
            WHERE
                    xdl2.application_id = 999
                AND xal2.application_id = 999
                AND xal2.ae_header_id = xdl2.ae_header_id
                AND xal2.ae_line_num = xdl2.ae_line_num
                AND xal2.overridden_code_combination_id IS NULL
                AND xal2.override_reason IS NOT NULL
                AND xdl2.source_distribution_type = 'xx_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL'
                AND xal2.ledger_id = xxx_rcpt_line.ledger_id
                AND xdl2.source_distribution_id_num_1 = xxx_rcpt_dist.source_distribution_id_num_1
                AND xdl2.ref_ae_header_id = xxx_rcpt_dist.ae_header_id
                AND xdl2.ref_ae_line_num = xxx_rcpt_dist.ae_line_num
        ) ) ) THEN
            'DEL'
        ELSE
            NULL
    END tax_line_user_attribute15
    << ... more where clauses ... >>
FROM
    xx_lines_det_factors            xx_det,
    xx_lines                        xx_line,
    xx_exemptions                   xx_ex,
    xx_taxes_b                      xx_tax,
    xx_accounts                     xx_accounts,
    xx_rates_vl                     xx_rate,
    xxx_events                      xxx_event,
    xxx_ae_headers                  xxx_head,
    xxx_ae_lines                    xxx_line,
    xxx_acct_class_assgns           acs,
    xxx_assignment_defns_b          asd,
    xxx_distribution_links          xxx_dist,
    xx_receivable_applications_all  ara,
    xxx_events                      xxx_rcpt_event,
    xxx_ae_headers                  xxx_rcpt_head,
    xxx_ae_lines                    xxx_rcpt_line,
    xxx_distribution_links          xxx_rcpt_dist,
    xx_distributions_all            ardist,
    xx_cust_trx_line_gl_dist_all    trx_dist,
    xx_customer_trx_lines_all       lines
WHERE
        xx_det.tax_reporting_flag = 'Y'
    << ... more where clauses ... >>
    AND 1 = 1;
```

The Explain plan is below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | exeOrd| Operation                                                    | Name                           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 |    66 | SELECT STATEMENT                                             |                                |       |       |       |   283K(100)|          |
|   1 |    65 |  NESTED LOOPS SEMI                                           |                                |     1 |   319 |       |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |    62 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED                        | xxx_distribution_links         |     1 |    50 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    61 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                                          | xxx_distribution_links_N1      |     2 |       |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    64 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                                | xxx_ae_lines                   |     1 |   269 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    63 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                         | xxx_ae_lines_U1                |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |    60 |  WINDOW SORT                                                 |                                |     1 |  2792 |       |   283K  (1)| 00:00:12 |
|   7 |    59 |   FILTER                                                     |                                |       |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |    58 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                        |                                |     1 |  2792 |       |   283K  (1)| 00:00:12 |
|   9 |    56 |     NESTED LOOPS                                             |                                |     1 |  2753 |       |   283K  (1)| 00:00:12 |
|  10 |    53 |      NESTED LOOPS                                            |                                |     1 |  2743 |       |   283K  (1)| 00:00:12 |
|  11 |    50 |       NESTED LOOPS                                           |                                |     1 |  2723 |       |   283K  (1)| 00:00:12 |
|  12 |    47 |        NESTED LOOPS                                          |                                |     1 |  2696 |       |   283K  (1)| 00:00:12 |
|  13 |    44 |         NESTED LOOPS                                         |                                |     1 |  2654 |       |   283K  (1)| 00:00:12 |
|  14 |    41 |          HASH JOIN                                           |                                |     1 |  2630 |       |   283K  (1)| 00:00:12 |
|  15 |    39 |           NESTED LOOPS                                       |                                |     1 |  2585 |       |   232K  (1)| 00:00:10 |
|  16 |    36 |            NESTED LOOPS                                      |                                |     1 |  2493 |       |   232K  (1)| 00:00:10 |
|  17 |    33 |             NESTED LOOPS                                     |                                |    15 | 36750 |       |   232K  (1)| 00:00:10 |
|  18 |    30 |              HASH JOIN                                       |                                |  2455 |  3735K|       |   225K  (1)| 00:00:09 |
|  19 |     1 |               TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                      | xx_rates_tl                    |    82 |  8938 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |    29 |               HASH JOIN                                      |                                |  2455 |  3473K|       |   225K  (1)| 00:00:09 |
|  21 |     2 |                TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                     | xx_rates_b                     |    82 |  6970 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |    28 |                HASH JOIN                                     |                                |  2455 |  3270K|       |   225K  (1)| 00:00:09 |
|  23 |     3 |                 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                    | xx_rates_b                     |    21 |   546 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  24 |    27 |                 NESTED LOOPS                                 |                                |  2455 |  3207K|       |   225K  (1)| 00:00:09 |
|  25 |    25 |                  NESTED LOOPS                                |                                |  9516 |  3207K|       |   225K  (1)| 00:00:09 |
|  26 |    23 |                   HASH JOIN                                  |                                |  2379 |  1119K|  8072K|   218K  (1)| 00:00:09 |
|  27 |    20 |                    JOIN FILTER CREATE                        | :BF0000                        |  2379 |  1119K|       |   218K  (1)| 00:00:09 |
|  28 |    19 |                     HASH JOIN                                |                                | 18159 |  7855K|  7680K|   190K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  29 |    16 |                      JOIN FILTER CREATE                      | :BF0001                        | 18159 |  7855K|       |   190K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  30 |    15 |                       HASH JOIN                              |                                | 18159 |  7465K|  7112K|   168K  (1)| 00:00:07 |
|  31 |    12 |                        JOIN FILTER CREATE                    | :BF0002                        | 18159 |  6898K|       |   115K  (1)| 00:00:05 |
|  32 |    11 |                         MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                 |                                | 18159 |  6898K|       |   115K  (1)| 00:00:05 |
|  33 |     7 |                          NESTED LOOPS                        |                                |     1 |   120 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  34 |     5 |                           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | xxx_assignment_defns_b         |     1 |    53 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  35 |     4 |                            INDEX SKIP SCAN                   | xxx_assignment_defns_b_U1      |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  36 |     6 |                           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | xxx_ACCT_CLASS_ASSGNS_U1       |     1 |    67 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|  37 |    10 |                          BUFFER SORT                         |                                |   329K|    84M|       |   115K  (1)| 00:00:05 |
|  38 |     9 |                           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| xxx_ae_lines                   |   329K|    84M|       |   115K  (1)| 00:00:05 |
|  39 |     8 |                            INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | xxx_ae_lines_N2                |  2084K|       |       |  6741   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  40 |    14 |                        JOIN FILTER USE                       | :BF0002                        |   844K|    25M|       | 50709   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  41 |    13 |                         TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL            | xxx_ae_headers                 |   844K|    25M|       | 50709   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  42 |    18 |                      JOIN FILTER USE                         | :BF0001                        |  2526K|    53M|       | 18048   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  43 |    17 |                       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL              | xxx_events                     |  2526K|    53M|       | 18048   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  44 |    22 |                    JOIN FILTER USE                           | :BF0000                        |   319K|    11M|       | 27552   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  45 |    21 |                     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                | xx_receivable_applications_all |   319K|    11M|       | 27552   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  46 |    24 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN                           | xx_LINES_N4                    |     4 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  47 |    26 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                 | xx_lines                       |     1 |   856 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  48 |    32 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED             | xx_lines_det_factors           |     1 |   892 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  49 |    31 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN                               | xx_LINES_DET_FACTORS_N2        |     3 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  50 |    35 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED              | xx_distributions_all           |     1 |    43 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  51 |    34 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN                                | xx_DISTRIBUTIONS_N1            |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  52 |    38 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED               | xxx_distribution_links         |     1 |    92 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  53 |    37 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                                 | xxx_distribution_links_N3      |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  54 |    40 |           TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                          | xxx_ae_headers                 | 26278 |  1154K|       | 50711   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  55 |    43 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED                 | xxx_ae_lines                   |     1 |    24 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  56 |    42 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                                   | xxx_ae_lines_U1                |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  57 |    46 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED                  | xxx_distribution_links         |     1 |    42 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  58 |    45 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN                                    | xxx_distribution_links_N3      |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  59 |    49 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                           | xx_cust_trx_line_gl_dist_all   |     1 |    27 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  60 |    48 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                    | xx_CUST_TRX_LINE_GL_DIST_U1    |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  61 |    52 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                            | xx_customer_trx_lines_all      |     1 |    20 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  62 |    51 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                     | xx_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINES_U1       |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  63 |    55 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED                     | xxx_events                     |     1 |    10 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  64 |    54 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                                       | xxx_EVENTS_U1                  |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  65 |    57 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                        | xx_ACCOUNTS_U2                 |     1 |    39 |       |     0   (0)|          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Based on some of our analysis, this is caused by a `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY` in the SELECTed columns. When i remove that Analytic Function, the explain plan removes the Full Table Scans:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | exeOrd| Operation                                             | Name                           | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 |    55 | SELECT STATEMENT                                      |                                |        |       |   504K(100)|          |
|   1 |    54 |  NESTED LOOPS                                         |                                |      1 |  2537 |   504K  (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   2 |    51 |   NESTED LOOPS                                        |                                |      1 |  2517 |   504K  (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   3 |    48 |    NESTED LOOPS                                       |                                |      1 |  2490 |   504K  (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   4 |    45 |     NESTED LOOPS                                      |                                |      1 |  2448 |   504K  (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   5 |    42 |      NESTED LOOPS                                     |                                |      1 |  2422 |   504K  (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   6 |    39 |       NESTED LOOPS                                    |                                |      1 |  1523 |   504K  (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   7 |    36 |        NESTED LOOPS                                   |                                |      9 | 13383 |   504K  (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   8 |    33 |         NESTED LOOPS                                  |                                |      9 | 13293 |   504K  (1)| 00:00:20 |
|*  9 |    30 |          HASH JOIN                                    |                                |    392 |   546K|   504K  (1)| 00:00:20 |
|  10 |    27 |           NESTED LOOPS                                |                                |      1 |  1403 |   340K  (1)| 00:00:14 |
|  11 |    24 |            NESTED LOOPS                               |                                |      1 |  1381 |   340K  (1)| 00:00:14 |
|* 12 |    21 |             HASH JOIN                                 |                                |      1 |  1271 |   340K  (1)| 00:00:14 |
|  13 |    19 |              NESTED LOOPS                             |                                |      1 |  1186 |   340K  (1)| 00:00:14 |
|  14 |    16 |               NESTED LOOPS                            |                                |   2752 |   857K|   333K  (1)| 00:00:14 |
|  15 |    13 |                NESTED LOOPS                           |                                |  12119 |  3313K|   311K  (1)| 00:00:13 |
|  16 |    10 |                 NESTED LOOPS                          |                                |  28044 |  6490K|   254K  (1)| 00:00:10 |
|  17 |     7 |                  NESTED LOOPS                         |                                |  22839 |  3234K|   163K  (1)| 00:00:07 |
|  18 |     4 |                   NESTED LOOPS                        |                                |      1 |   120 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |     2 |                    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| xla_assignment_defns_b         |      1 |    53 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |     1 |                     INDEX SKIP SCAN                   | XLA_ASSIGNMENT_DEFNS_B_U1      |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |     3 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | XLA_ACCT_CLASS_ASSGNS_U1       |      1 |    67 |     0   (0)|          |
|* 22 |     6 |                   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | xla_ae_lines                   |    414K|     9M|   163K  (1)| 00:00:07 |
|* 23 |     5 |                    INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | XLA_AE_LINES_N2                |   2824K|       |  9684   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |     9 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED  | xla_distribution_links         |      1 |    92 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 25 |     8 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | XLA_DISTRIBUTION_LINKS_N3      |      1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 26 |    12 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | ar_distributions_all           |      1 |    43 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 27 |    11 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | AR_DISTRIBUTIONS_U2            |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 28 |    15 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | ar_receivable_applications_all |      1 |    39 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 29 |    14 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | AR_RECEIVABLE_APPLICATIONS_U1  |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 30 |    18 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED     | zx_lines                       |      1 |   867 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 31 |    17 |                INDEX RANGE SCAN                       | ZX_LINES_N4                    |      4 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  32 |    20 |              TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                | zx_rates_b                     |      1 |    85 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  33 |    23 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID               | zx_rates_tl                    |      1 |   110 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 34 |    22 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                        | ZX_RATES_TL_U1                 |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 35 |    26 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED        | xla_events                     |      1 |    22 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 36 |    25 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                          | XLA_EVENTS_U1                  |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 37 |    29 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED         | xla_ae_lines                   |    414K|     9M|   163K  (1)| 00:00:07 |
|* 38 |    28 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN                           | XLA_AE_LINES_N2                |   2824K|       |  9685   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 39 |    32 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                  | xla_ae_headers                 |      1 |    49 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 40 |    31 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                           | XLA_AE_HEADERS_U1              |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 41 |    35 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED           | xla_events                     |      1 |    10 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 42 |    34 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN                             | XLA_EVENTS_U1                  |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 43 |    38 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                    | xla_ae_headers                 |      1 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 44 |    37 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                             | XLA_AE_HEADERS_U1              |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 45 |    41 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED             | zx_lines_det_factors           |      1 |   899 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 46 |    40 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                               | ZX_LINES_DET_FACTORS_N2        |      3 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  47 |    44 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                      | zx_taxes_b                     |      1 |    26 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 48 |    43 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                               | ZX_TAXES_B_U1                  |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 49 |    47 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED               | xla_distribution_links         |      1 |    42 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 50 |    46 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                                 | XLA_DISTRIBUTION_LINKS_N3      |      1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 51 |    50 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                        | ra_cust_trx_line_gl_dist_all   |      1 |    27 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 52 |    49 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                 | RA_CUST_TRX_LINE_GL_DIST_U1    |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 53 |    53 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                         | ra_customer_trx_lines_all      |      1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 54 |    52 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                  | RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINES_U1       |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I plan to move that Analytic function to a separate Procedure, similar to something like below (not yet the exact procedure):

```
procedure Identify_duplicates (p_request_id number)
as

    cursor cur_duplicate_information (p_request_id number)
    is
    SELECT
        REP_TBL_ID,     -- UNIQUE IDENTIFIER
        CASE
            WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY xxrtbl.accounting_class_code, xxrtbl.source_distribution_id_num_1, xxrtbl.event_id) = 1 THEN
                NULL
            WHEN ( ( xxx_rcpt_line.overridden_code_combination_id IS NULL
                    AND xxx_rcpt_line.override_reason IS NOT NULL )
                OR ( EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    'Reversal of original due to override exists'
                FROM
                    xxx_ae_lines            xal2,
                    xxx_distribution_links  xdl2
                WHERE
                        xdl2.application_id = 999
                    AND xal2.application_id = 999
                    AND xal2.ae_header_id = xdl2.ae_header_id
                    AND xal2.ae_line_num = xdl2.ae_line_num
                    AND xal2.overridden_code_combination_id IS NULL
                    AND xal2.override_reason IS NOT NULL
                    AND xdl2.source_distribution_type = 'xx_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL'
                    AND xal2.ledger_id = xxrtbl.ledger_id
                    AND xdl2.source_distribution_id_num_1 = xxrtbl.source_distribution_id_num_1
                    AND xdl2.ref_ae_header_id = xxrtbl.ae_header_id
                    AND xdl2.ref_ae_line_num = xxrtbl.ae_line_num
            ) ) ) THEN
                'DEL'
            ELSE
                NULL
        END     tax_line_user_attribute15
    FROM    XX_REP_TABLE xxrtbl
    WHERE   REQ_ID = p_request_id;
    
    type typ_dup_info   cur_duplicate_information%type;
    rec_dup_info        typ_dup_info;
        
begin

    OPEN cur_duplicate_information;
    FETCH cur_duplicate_information
    BULK COLLECT 
    INTO  rec_dup_info
    CLOSE cur_duplicate_information;
    
    forall  rec_dup_info.first .. rec_dup_info.last
    UPDATE  XX_REP_TABLE
    SET     tax_line_user_attribute15 =  rec_dup_info(i).tax_line_user_attribute15
    where   REP_TBL_ID = REP_TBL_ID(i).REP_TBL_ID;
    
exception
    when others then 
        dbms_output.put_line('Error in :'||SQLERRM);
    raise;
end;
```

I am curious to find out if this will make any difference.
Will "adding" the two explain plans provide a rough estimate of the total cost?

Note: i cannot run this from our own instances because there is too few records to have an actual impact. This performance issue was from our customer and they have billions of records, which we cannot export or mimic. Hence, I wanted to "theoretically" calculate it first before making the code fix.

Comment: _"am curious to find out if this will make any difference. "_   So why not just try it and _see_ if it makes any difference?     "_ is there any way i can add two explain plans together?_"  This makes no sense.  What do you think it even _means_ to "add two explain plans together"?

Comment: Most people tend to use the total cost and/or time when comparing two queries. It's not really perfectly comparable in your case since the second query will have a little bit of overhead (parsing etc). But I think you could add the costs of the 2 split queries together and compare them to the original cost for a rough estimate.

Comment: @EdStevens unfortunately, i cannot run this from our own instances because there is too few records to have an actual impact. This performance issue was from our customer and they have billions of records, which we cannot export or mimic. Hence, I wanted to "theoretically" calculate it first before making the code fix.

Comment: You may be able to refactor your query to replace COUNT OVER PARTITION by a joined subquery with GROUP BY in it. If you can do that, you may get a plan that's more useful for the purpose of working out an appropriate covering index. And if worst comes to worst, you can try stashing that subquery in a materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b) 
  FROM table
```

gives similar results to

```
SELECT t.a, t.b, q.number
  FROM table t
  JOIN ( SELECT b, COUNT(*) number
           FROM table
          GROUP BY b
       ) q ON t.b = q.b
```

The subquery in the second item can exploit an index on `b`.

Without seeing your entire query, it's hard to guess how to refactor it to use such a subquery.

And, by the way, as long as you're working on that chunk of code, you should consider bringing it into the 1990s by using explicit JOINs.  Instead of this

```
SELECT ... 
  FROM t1, t2, t3
 WHERE t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
   AND t2.t2_id = t3.t2_id(+)
```

Use this

```
SELECT ...
  FROM t1
 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
  LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.t2_id = t3.t2_id
```

The comma-join syntax was replaced by explicit joins in SQL-92, a generation ago.